# How to run a specific schema with a specific build configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

Flutter allow us to specify a flavor but on IOS we can have schema and build configuration.
How to run a specific schema with a specific build configuration ?
I've one project with 2 targets (same codebase) :

- ClientA
- ClientB

For each client I've two sub build configuration : development & production (two firebase app).
Flutter ask me to put the schema on the flavor flag :

```
The Xcode project defines schemes: ClientA, ClientB
Exception: You must specify a --flavor option to select one of the available schemes.
```

But after doing that, issue around build configuration :

```
The Xcode project defines build configurations: Debug-prod, Debug-dev, Release-prod, Release-dev, Profil-prod, Profile-dev
Flutter expects a build configuration named Debug-ClientA or similar.
```

Tell me if I miss something, but I think that flavor is for build configuration and not for schema...
Anyone can help me  ?

I would avoid many target like following because it seems not to be Apple guidelines :

- ClientA-dev
- ClientA-prod
- ClientB-dev
- ClientB-prod

Comment: Any updates with this problem? I have a similar problem

Comment: @JanneckLange You need to create a new scheme inside Xcode. Then dupplicate build-configuration Debug / Profl / Release for this new scheme.